# Using an eval() result to fill a form in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

How can we pass the value of `eval()` to a variable for filling a password text box.

Here is my CasperJS code. It is showing that it can't find variable `y`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var casper = require ('casper').create();
var page = require('webpage').create();

casper.start('http://thedemosite.co.uk/login.php', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.capture('loginbefore.bmp');

    casper.then ( function () {
        casper.evaluate(function(username, password) {
           document.querySelector('#username').value = username;
           document.querySelector('#password').value = password;
           document.querySelector('#FormsButton2').click();
        }, 'PP406214795IN', y));

        casper.then (function () {
            var fs = require('fs');
            var test = fs.read('readingjs.js');
            var y = eval(test);
        });
        this.wait(5000, function() {
            this.echo("I've waited for a  5 second.");
        });
    });
});
casper.run();
```

Comment: i want that y variable is a result evaluated script i.e( a string of numbers ex. 125402) to be filled in the textbox and preceedin with a click to get the login forward..

Comment: really sorry for the inconvenience caused for the code indentation,   i have tried it but the html page in stackflow showing good while editing when posting it ..it is not as per

Comment: Did my answer help? If it didn't, please describe what the issue is. If it did, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

- Variables that are defined through the `var` keyword in JavaScript are in the local function scope. They are only accessible in this function and closures defined in this function. If you want to use a global variable, then you need to define it either in the global scope or in a higher function scope.
- All `casper.then*()` and `casper.wait*()` are asynchronous step functions. This means that they are executed one after the other in the order you called them. Since you use `y` before you define it, you will need to exchange the ordering, but keep in mind that all the other functions such as `casper.evaluate()` are not asynchronous which means that if you call `casper.then()` before `casper.evaluate()`, the code inside `then()` will be executed after the `evaluate()` code.

Since `fs.read()` and `eval()` are synchronous functions, you can simply move the file reading and `eval`ing up like this:

```
casper.start('http://thedemosite.co.uk/login.php', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.capture('loginbefore.bmp');
});

casper.then(function(){
    var fs = require('fs');
    var test = fs.read('readingjs.js');
    var y = eval(test);

    this.evaluate(function(username, password) {
       document.querySelector('#username').value = username;
       document.querySelector('#password').value = password;
    }, 'PP406214795IN', y);
    this.click('#FormsButton2');
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.capture("loginAfter.png");
});

casper.run();
```